# Is this simple proof of Archimedes' Property valid?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

A simple proof of Archimedes' Property (of analysis)?

I'm working an example given on page 16 of Shilov's "Real and Complex Analysis," which is his proof of Archimedes' Property:

Given arbitrary real numbers $x > 0$ and $y, \exists n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(n-1)x \le y \lt nx.$


He provides a proof which appears to be correct, but is this simpler proof valid?
Proof:
For each $n \in \mathbb{Z}, $ define the half-open interval $I_n:= [(n-1)x,nx).$ This partitions the real line, so since $y\in \mathbb{R}, y $ belongs to one of the $I_n.$ Thus $(n-1)x \le y \lt nx.$

Comment: [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) is a law of physics fundamental to fluid mechanics.  I think you mean the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)

Comment: Given $x>0$, how do you prove that the set $\{[(n-1)x,nx) : n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is a partition of $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 3):

The claim

> This partitions the real line

needs justification, and in fact is what you're trying to prove in disguise. So that argument doesn't work - something more complicated is needed. You need to use properties of $\mathbb{R}$ in a nontrivial way.

To elaborate on the previous sentence, there are such things as *non-Archimedean* ordered fields - structures where addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division make sense and behave basically as we expect them to, but which do not satisfy the Archimedean property. The crucial property of $\mathbb{R}$ is its **completeness** (and in fact $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique-up-to-isomorphism complete ordered field).